# how can I collect the value(s) of a class and pass it/them to the controller in asp.net with @Html.CheckBox or @Html.CheckBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, asp.net-core, checkbox

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdDepartamento)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombreDep)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdDepartamento)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreDep)
                </td>
                <td>
                   @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsCheck)
                  
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Ver empleados" />
```

my Model:
  #region Properties

```
    public bool IsCheck { get ; set ; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public vistaEjercicio_MODEL()
    {
        IsCheck = false;
        
    }


    #endregion
```

and my viewModel is a list of the model

it does not return any value to the controller, it comes with id=0, phase and without department name
I expected to receive a class of the model with the necessary data to be able to follow the project, but I have already commented the object of the class arrives empty, I have looked for thousand ways to use it, but I am not able to hit the target. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Do you mean add a checkbox so you can selects a row from the list , and pass that row to the controller ?

Comment: Exactly!! what I want to achieve is that when I check several checkboxes I get back in the view the selected lists.